# How do I add i386 architecture in Ubuntu MATE 15.04?

Tags: apt, package-management, wine, dpkg, playonlinux

So I want to install wine:i386 so I can use PlayOnLinux.

http://wiki.playonlinux.com/index.php/Installing_PlayOnLinux

> For users' Debian wheezy and Ubuntu Precise (and higher), they'll need to install the i386 version of Wine. For this, we must enable support for i386 in your repository manager.

`sudo echo "foreign-i386 architecture"> /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch` simply returned nothing and jumped to the next line. I checked the file later and it had been edited to contain the line "foreign-i386 architecture".

`sudo apt-get update` worked just fine.

`sudo apt-get install wine:i386` returned 
`Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y` after which it returned:

```
Extracting templates from packages: 100%
Preconfiguring packages ...
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'foreign-i386'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

"unknown option 'foreign-i386'".

How can I resolve this?

P.S. I'm very new to Linux, please be patient.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check that the only file in the below folder is multiarch using:-

`ls /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/`

See if the output is `multiarch`.
If the output is multiarch then run below:-

`sudo sh -c "echo 'foreign-architecture i386' > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch"`

**NOTE:-** First, check the output of `uname -m`, if it is already i386, then no-need to follow above steps, i.e, i386 is enabled by default.

Comment: The `ls` command returned nothing, I went to the folder manually through the file manager and certainly, there was nothing there.

Comment: What is the output of `uname -m` ?

Comment: i686. This is a sentence so the comment is long enough.

Comment: @AdamGenell Then you don't need to do anything, just do this `sudo apt-get install wine` . You should have check it first :) BTW Accept one of the answer as they both should have worked!

Comment: What you said is that if the output was i386 then I wouldn't have to do anything.  The output was i686.

Comment: @AdamGenell It applies to both

Comment: i686 itself is an impementation of i386!

Comment: Ah thanks man, I tested it and it worked like a charm. How to I mark this as solved?

Comment: @AdamGenell Click on the tick on my answer (below the down-arrow near the answer score) and click that upper arrow if you have'nt already. :)

Answer (score 8):

To resolve it, run this command:

```
sudo dpkg --add-architecture i386
```

Or, if fails, you can still add it using the other answer's method below.

Comment: That returns `dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'foreign-i386'`

Comment: This "--foreign-architecture" is the old method. The new one is "--add-architecture" See: http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/vivid/man1/dpkg.1.html

Comment: @AdamGenell please try the edit (that one should work)

Comment: @AdamGenell just remove the multiarch file before you try to add it, because it's reading foreign-architecture and that's the reason to do not continue.