# Can't Install Wine1.6 on 64bit

Tags: wine, dependencies

I trying to install wine with

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

and Terminal showing this

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu4) but it is not installable
           Recommends: cups-bsd but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: gnome-exe-thumbnailer but it is not going to be installed or
                       kde-runtime but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-droid but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-liberation but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-mscorefonts-installer but it is not installable
           Recommends: fonts-horai-umefont but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: fonts-unfonts-core but it is not going to be installed
           Recommends: ttf-wqy-microhei
           Recommends: winbind but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Wait, I'm adding my answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For Wine to work on a 64 bit machine, you need to enable support for i386 architecture. To do this, follow these steps:

> Check that the only file in the below folder is multiarch using:-
>
> ```
> ls /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/
> ```
>
> See if the output is multiarch. If the output is multiarch then run
>   below:-
>
> ```
> sudo sh -c "echo 'foreign-architecture i386' > /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch"
> ```
>
> NOTE:- First, check the output of `uname -m`, if it is already i386,
>   then no-need to follow above steps, i.e, i386 is enabled by default.

Above is quoted from [my answer here](https://askubuntu.com/a/633657/408593).

Follow the above steps and then do:

```
sudo apt-get install wine1.6
```

Comment: I normally do this and found the above didn't work. http://realtechtalk.com/Ubuntu_Debian_Linux_Cannot_Install_Wine_Solution__wine16_Depends_wine16i386_11620ubuntu142_but_it_is_not_installable_wine14_Depends_wine16_but_it_is_not_going_to_be_installed-2289-articles

Answer (score 0):

Before trying to install wine, add the wine ppa in the sources list by the command `sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-wine/ppa`. Then update the sources using `sudo apt-get update`. Now install wine using `sudo apt-get install wine1.6`.
GOOD LUCK...