# Dependency errors for wine and VirtualBox on 16.04

Tags: package-management, virtualbox, dependencies, multiarch

I was trying to install VirtualBox. This is the output I get when I run `sudo apt install virtualbox`

```
$ sudo apt install virtualbox
[sudo] password for gurvinder: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 virtualbox : Depends: virtualbox-dkms (>= 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                       virtualbox-source (>= 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed or
                       virtualbox-modules
              Depends: libgsoap8 but it is not going to be installed
              Recommends: virtualbox-qt (= 5.0.40-dfsg-0ubuntu1.16.04.1) but it is not going to be installed
 wine1.6 : Depends: wine1.6-i386 (= 1:1.6.2-0ubuntu14.2) but it is not installable
           Recommends: fonts-droid but it is not installable
E: Unmet dependencies. Try 'apt-get -f install' with no packages (or specify a solution).
gurvinder@gurvinder-Inspiron-3558:~$ sudo apt -f install
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  cabextract fonts-horai-umefont fonts-unfonts-core gnome-exe-thumbnailer
  icoutils libasn1-8-heimdal:i386 libcapi20-3 libcapi20-3:i386 libdb5.3:i386
  libdbus-glib-1-2:i386 libdbusmenu-gtk3-4:i386 libexif12:i386 libgd3:i386
  libgif7:i386 libgphoto2-6:i386 libgphoto2-port12:i386 libgsf-1-114
  libgsf-1-common libgssapi3-heimdal:i386 libhcrypto4-heimdal:i386
  libheimbase1-heimdal:i386 libheimntlm0-heimdal:i386 libhx509-5-heimdal:i386
  libieee1284-3:i386 libkrb5-26-heimdal:i386 libldap-2.4-2:i386 libltdl7:i386
  libmpg123-0:i386 libmsi0 libmspack0 libodbc1 libopenal1:i386 libosmesa6
  libosmesa6:i386 libp11-kit-gnome-keyring:i386 libqt4-designer libqt4-help
  libqt4-opengl libqt4-scripttools libqt4-svg libqt4-test
  libqtassistantclient4 libqtwebkit4 libroken18-heimdal:i386 libsane:i386
  libsasl2-2:i386 libsasl2-modules:i386 libsasl2-modules-db:i386
  libusb-1.0-0:i386 libwind0-heimdal:i386 libxdo3 libxpm4:i386 msitools
  ocl-icd-libopencl1:i386 odbcinst odbcinst1debian2 p11-kit-modules:i386 p7zip
  python-gobject python-qt4 python-sip ttf-mscorefonts-installer
  ttf-wqy-microhei unixodbc wine-gecko2.21 wine-gecko2.21:i386 wine-mono0.0.8
  winetricks xdotool
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  wine1.6 wine1.6-amd64 wine1.6-i386:i386
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 9 not upgraded.
After this operation, 245 MB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'foreign-architecture'
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (2)
```

Comment: please [edit] your question, and copy/paste the **text** of the error instead of the **image** you provided.

Comment: Please execute the command `dpkg --print-foreign-architectures` and append the result of the command into your question

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I add i386 architecture in Ubuntu MATE 15.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/633654/how-do-i-add-i386-architecture-in-ubuntu-mate-15-04)

Comment: This is the output of the command dpkg --print-foreign-architectures

dpkg: error: configuration error: /etc/dpkg/dpkg.cfg.d/multiarch:1: unknown option 'foreign-architecture'