# Unable to install Steam on latest 64bit desktop version of ubuntu for PI4

Tags: steam

I'm using the desktop 64bit version of Ubuntu Linux for raspberry pi 4 (8G) (Latest version as of the 26th of December 2020) i can't download Steam, the Linux version from their website, and the one from Ubuntu's software store. I'll be talking about both. for the website download, it says i don't have libc.so.6, and for the Ubuntu software store, it says that it's "missing the following dependencies:" but it doesn't list any dependencies, it just ends the message. any suggestions, I barely know anything about the terminal and almost all "fixes" for these issues don't seem to work. any ideas?

Comment: Did you add the i386 architecutre support? See https://askubuntu.com/questions/633654/how-do-i-add-i386-architecture-in-ubuntu-mate-15-04

Comment: @ubfan1 it's a r.pi so *arm64*, I don't think i386 will be that helpful...

Comment: Steam is i386, so it does not run natively on arm64.  Either run Steam on a machine which supports i386 and use something like steamlink on the arm64 machine or try a i386 virtual machine.